# Rails - ActionCable: "action_cable.url" for Kubernetes/Minikube

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, kubernetes, minikube, actioncable

What **config.action_cable.url** should be configured for websockets / Rails / Kubernetes /Minukube with Nginx?

When running "docker-compose" locally an Nginx processes in front of a Rails process (not API only, but with SSR)  and a standalone Cable process (cf [the guides](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_cable_overview.html#standalone)), the websockets work fine by passing the following server-side (in say "/config/application.rb", with `action_cable_meta_tag` set in the layouts):

```rb
config.action_cable.url = 'ws://localhost:28080'
```

I am targetting Kubernetes with Minikube locally:  I deployed Nginx in front of a Rails deployment (RAILS_ENV=production) along with a Cable deployment but I can't make it work. The Cable service is internal of type "ClusterIP", with "port" and "targetPort". I tried several variations.

Any advice?

Note that I use Nginx -> Rails + Cable on Minikube, and the entry-point is the Nginx service, external of kind LoadBalancer where I used:

```
upstream rails {
  server rails-svc:3000;
}
server {
  listen 9000 default_server;
  root /usr/share/nginx/html;
  try_files  $uri @rails;
  add_header  Cache-Control public;
  add_header  Last-Modified "";
  add_header  Etag "";
      

  location @rails {
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_pass_header   Set-Cookie;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_pass http://rails;

    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
  }
}
```

To allow any origin, I also set:

```rb
config.action_cable.disable_request_forgery_protection = true
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have an answer: in a Minikube cluster, don't put anything and disable forgery protection, Rails will default the correct value. When Nginx is front of a Rails pod and a standalone ActionCable/websocket pod (the Rails image is launched with `bundle exec puma -p 28080 cable/config.ru`), if I name "cable-svc" the service that exposes the ActionCable container, and "rails-svc" the one for the Rails container, you need to:

- in K8, don't set the config for `CABLE_URI`
- in the Rails backend, you don't have the URL (unknown `127.0.0.1:some_port`), do:

```rb
# config.action_cable.url <-- comment this
config.action_cable.disable_request_forgery_protection=true
```

- in the Nginx config, add a specific location for the "/cable" path:

```
upstream rails {
  server rails-svc:3000;
}
server {
  [...root, location @rails {...}]
  location /cable {
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
    proxy_pass "http://cable-svc:28080";
  }
}
```

Check the logs, no more WebSockets in Rails, and Cable responds.

Comment: did you manage to setup probes (startup/liveness/readiness) for the action_cable pod ? I'm having trouble with errors like `Failed to upgrade to WebSocket (REQUEST_METHOD: GET, HTTP_CONNECTION: upgrade, HTTP_UPGRADE: Websocket)`

Comment: No, I couldn't either set up a working probe on the /cable endpoint.